# NullPointerException: Attempt 'void com.mobiledealer.dao.OrderDAO.insertOrUpdate(com.mobiledealer.model.Order)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, json, rest, retrofit2

Hi I have problem with response from REST. I receive Object Json parse it and everything look fine but when i try add it to Realm i get Null Pointer Exception.
This is link to my project:
https://github.com/666Angelus666/MobileDealer

In `MainActivity` I call function `synchronizeContractorsItems` then in the 3-th Call i'm get the error.
[Line where i get error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyypG.png)

Comment: Please include code and stack trace in the question, and not the screenshot.

Comment: You got a `null` in the list....

Comment: Paste the code here. We shouldn't have to dig through your repo in order to find the code that you need help with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen your code. I think this issue is because you did not initialize your `orderDAO` object in your activity you have to initialize your `orderDAO` object before using

```
orderDAO = new OrderDAO();


Call<OrderResponse> orderResponseCall = apiService.getOrdersList();
        orderResponseCall.enqueue(new Callback<OrderResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<OrderResponse> call, Response<OrderResponse> response) {
                orderList = response.body().getOrdersList();

                for (Order order : orderList) {
                    try {
                        orderDAO.insertOrUpdate(order);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.d("REST", "Error");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }`
```

I think this may solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, you are right i forget initialize `orderDAO` after i do that code start working. Thx for help.

Comment: I'm glad to know that I could help you ! Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

The suspect may be your order could be null, may be a null check would help

```
 public void insertOrUpdate(Order order) {

 if(order != null)

 {

    realm.beginTransaction();
    realm.insertOrUpdate(order);
    realm.commitTransaction();

 }

    }`
```